# Online store database entity relationship diagram is correct?

Tags: mysql

I created schema of database shopping online. I want to know if this schema is correct, if relations between tables are correct and if missing any table ? I will grafefull for every helps and tips.

[image: MySQL Diagram]

Comment: Fix the inconsistency in `products.id_category`.  And provide some representative `SELECTs`.

Answer (score 0):

You schema is good for buying product only one product each order, if you wish every customer can buy multiple products, better your create one another table product_order, relation many to many between orders and products.

Comment: I modifyed my schema database if now is correct ?

Comment: This answer is opinionated and extremely broad. It's also not likely to be useful to anyone besides the OP since this is an *extremely* specific question. Because of the very nature of this question, there is no correct (objective) answer to it. There is just way too much that would need to be covered in a "correct" answer that simply just can't be in a Stack Overflow answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Relation between customers and orders (one to many) must be like
   this because customers by default don't have any charges (you sets
   as one or many) [image]

2. For one order many payments can exist, in my opinion, it's hard to
   realize, but much easier to create one for one order one amount
   (Compile cost for all products from order)
3. Products and opinions relation. One opinion for many products
   doesn't look good. Maybe set many ideas for one product
4. Don't use VARCHAR format for passwords, use CHAR

That can be incorrect because I don't know how that must work